# My new laptop keeps killing externals

Tags: laptop, ssd, external-hard-drive, windows-11

My HP Envy x360 2 in 1 laptop 15-fe0053dx that I got this last (2023) black Friday keeps killing my external hard drives. After purchasing it I also bought a 1tb Crucial external SDD and a 1TB Seagate Backup Plus slim HDD.

After less than a month neither of them was working. I returned them and got a 2TB Seagate Backup Plus slim HDD. Same deal. I am now using a WD Black 5TB HDD and I just got an error code 7 in the HDD smart test, while I get this in Crystal Disk Info.

[image: CrystalDiskinfo screen shot]

Comment: What's meant by "_killing my external hard drives_" & "_neither of them was working_"? Laptops can't output more than 5V from the USB port's 5V circuit since other component failures would be noticed; even then, only the case's SATA to USB PCB would be fried, not the drive itself. Coincidence doesn't equal correlation - has a known good USB cable been tried? Is the drive being moved, bumped, or jostled when in use? What's the output of a long S.M.A.R.T test and `smartctl -a`? Using [`smartctl`](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download) directly is better than CrystalDiskInfo